# Validating String in PHP with pattern match

Tags: php

Hey could someone help me to test if a string matches 3 double digit figures separated by a colon? For Example:

12:13:14

I understand I should be using preg_match but I can't work out how

Preferably the first number should be between 0 and 23 and the second two numbers should be between 0 and 59 like a time but I can always work that out with if statements.

Thanks

Comment: Here's a great reference site for learning regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Do the minute and second fields have to be two digits (e.g., `:04:09`) or no leading zeros (e.g., `:4:9`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [preg_match](http://co.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with number comparissons on `$string = '23:24:25';`

```
preg_match('~^(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$~', $string, $matches);

if (count($matches) != 3 || $matches[1] > 23 || $matches[2] > 59 || $matches[3] > 59 ......)
    die('The digits are not right');
```

Or you can even ditch the regular expresions and use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with numeric comparisons.

```
$numbers = explode(':', $string);

if (count($numbers) != 3 || $numbers[0] > 23 || $numbers[1] > 59 || $numbers[2] > 59 ......)
    die('The digits are not right');
```

Comment: The first of these answers will not accept the strings where the second digit of the hours is greater than 3, or second digit of minutes or seconds is 6,7 or 8 (e.g. "14:00:00", "12:07:00", "12:00:07"). The second answer will accept a correct value srrounded by junk (e.g. "012:34:56789"). The third answer will accept non-numeric values (e.g. "a:b:c"), missing parts (e.g. "12:34") or even an empty string ("").

Comment: before running the if, check if `sizeof($numbers)` returns `>= 2`

Comment: You are right! I corrected the answer and deleted the first part. I left the other ones because they use numeric comparisons to validate that the string has the desired format.

Answer (score 1):

This answer does correct matching across the entire string (other answers will match the regexp within a longer string), without any extra tests required:

```
if (preg_match('/^((?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:2[0-3])):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$/', $string, $matches))
{
    print_r($matches);
}
else
{
    echo "Does not match\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$regex = "/\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d/";

$subject = "12:13:14";

preg_match($regex, $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match ('/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/', $input)) {
    // matches
} else {
    // doesnt match
}
```

`\d` means any digit, so groups of two of those with `:` in between.